# Implementing DNS over TLS on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dns, bind

I am not very familiar with Linux, as I have predominantly been involved with everything Microsoft for the majority of my IT life, but I am just looking at the possibility of implementing a pair of Ubuntu DNS Servers that will perform external lookups using Cloudflare's DNS over TLS.

I have read some articles saying that you can use:

- Stubby
- Bind9 with stunnel
- nginx as a TLS proxy

However, I am not sure of the best and easiest method and just wondered if anyone had an opinion on what I should be using and if there is any documentation on how to setup and configure.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, DNS over TLS (DoT) should be implemented on the gateway (edge router) of the network, for a home or small office network, it should be implemented on the Internet Gateway. This approach has low management / ops overhead as it is transparent to the clients (configuration can be pushed to clients via DHCP, or manually set).

For example, at home I use AsusWRT-Merlin powered router to do DNS privacy (DoT).

If DoT is only required for a single host, e.g, Linux Server or workstation, use `systemd-resolved is the easiest (OS level).